# English dictionary dump for text analysis

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for an English Dictionary dump for some text analysis in Python.
This would include a word and some of its attributes (noun/verb, its forms, tenses, and probably origin too!). So, I envision these as columns of a data frame.
I have gone through numerous threads where folks have suggested some sources but I believe none of those fulfill the above requirements (some are just word lists, others are words with just meanings). Moreover, they kind of look non-exhaustive (very small corpus whereas I am targeting to have ~500000 words).
Is there a dump available from authoritative sources like Oxford or Merriam Webster?
Also, there is a PyDictionary module. Is it possible to fetch such a dump from this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordNet is a corpus of words, their synonyms, hyponyms, and meronyms, grouped by synsets and made available for free give that you follow their license. https://wordnet.princeton.edu/. Since this is a popular choice, you can find this corpus in almost any data format with a little searching. Database contains 155,327 words.

BabelNet is another corpus that have aggregated WordNet, Wikipedia, and many other sources into a database of 91,218,220 glossary definitions covering many languages. https://babelnet.org/

If you want to use the Oxford dictionary and Merriam Webster, they are commercial products who dont throw around their database with unlimited access. Both have API interfaces you can gain access to with a registered API key.